# Cannot read 433Mhz data

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

My goal is to use a 433Mhz receiver to capture the KlikAanKlikUit (Kaku/CoCo) ID.

I have it wired to 5V and GPIO4. When reading up on the subject there are a few tools to capture data and even capture the KaKu ID directly. None of these seem to work, they just do nothing.

The receiver is named `XD-RF-5V`. Please see some pictures of the set-up at the end of the questions.

When I use the excellent [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) I can see that 'something' is happening, also when I press some buttons on the remote.  See a video of it here: http://recordit.co/8kpG42adjl

I have used https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils 's RFSniffer with no results but I can also see that tool is hardcoded to use pin 2. I've changed my set-up to GPIO0/1/2 to try but also no results. To be honest i'm also completely confused by all the pin standards, some use wiringPI, some use BCM, some use real numbers...

When I use [pilight](https://www.pilight.org/), which installs fine, and use their `pilight-raw` command with these settings:

```
{
        "devices": {},
        "rules": {},
        "gui": {},
        "settings": {
                "log-level": 6,
                "pid-file": "/var/run/pilight.pid",
                "log-file": "/var/log/pilight.log",
                "webserver-enable": 1,
                "webserver-root": "/usr/local/share/pilight/",
                "webserver-http-port": 5001,
                "webserver-cache": 1
        },
        "hardware": {
                "433gpio": {
                        "sender": 0,
                        "receiver": 4
                }
        },
        "registry": {
                "pilight": {
                        "version": {
                                "current": "7.0"
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

Nothing happens, except for the first line. According to the docs it should just keep outputting data.

[image]

[image: http://imgur.com/xGbz9hr]
[image]

Comment: Since you have got piscope installed you might as well try http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2__433D or http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python__433_py.  The first one is more recent and I suggest you try that first.  Does the piscope trace look like a Manchester encoded signal?  Do you get much noise?

Comment: @joan yeah I believe it's Manchester encoded, see the video I made. Not sure how to differentiate with noise or background signals. I'll have a look at those code samples. thanks

Comment: I had a look at the video and it appears to be Manchester encoding but there does appear to be some noise.  You'd expect pulses of two different lengths.  Every now and then there is a short pulse which shouldn't be there.  Both the linked software examples will filter out the noise which will make the likelihood of decoding the signal higher.

Comment: pigpio only uses Broadcom GPIO numbering, see http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html#Type_3

Comment: @joan thanks a lot! I hope to find some time this weekend to try it out, i'll report back!

Comment: @joan: So i've managed to find some time. Your code looks good but it doesn't print out anything. The python script once printed out a `0` but that was after I pushed the `on` button on my remote already 50 times.
I don't have a lot of hardware/electronic tricks on my sleeve to reduce the noise.

Comment: There's not much to go wrong.  Check that you are using the correct GPIO.  piscope can save the data to a file if you set a start and stop point (after capturing the data).  If you can dump the data it might help.

Comment: Just to be 100% sure, piscope `18 (CE0)` corresponds with `./_433D -r18` right?

Comment: also captured some data, not sure what to do with that... https://gist.github.com/tomvo/a03ffb04a53849fd1616052e27bd5ccc. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Yes, GPIO18 (CE0) and -r18 are correct.  Okay I loaded the data back into piscope.  You seem to have a signal on GPIO18 and on GPIO28.  The GPIO28 looks like it may be caused by interference from GPIO18.  Trouble is neither look like Manchester encoding.

Comment: Ah ok, that's a bummer. Maybe I should just order a new one and some jumper cables I can directly plug-in to the PI without the breadboard thing i'm using. Maybe it's caused by the fact i'm always logged-in over wifi and not directly on the device itself.

Comment: I haven't really looked at your photo before.  You don't seem to have an aerial on the receiver.  On the cheap modules I buy you have to solder a 16cm length of wire to a point on the receiver and transmitter for the aerial(s).  That could account for the poor signals.

Comment: @joan: thanks a lot for your help, I managed to solve it using an Arduino. Now just to figure out how I can talk to the Arduino from my python script. I do have another problem now however which looks a little more serious: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51932/dht22-return-999-all-pins-that-that-i-connect-it-to-give-oscillating-values-af

Answer (score 1):

I got the same sensor you are using STX882/SRX882.

To solve the problem:

1. if you are using wiringPi you could call
   gpio mode  tri (to disable internal resistance of RPI), than your sensor will start to work, otherwise it will be in SLEEP mode
2. Connect it to 3.3V (not to 5V) GPIOs cannot support more than 3.3V (otherwise u will burn the GPIO Pin)

See the sensor Specification to see more info